# Треугольники Python

Tags: python, фракталы

[image]

Нужно чтобы вначале рисовался треугольник, внутри него еще 3, внутри трех еще 3 и так далее.

Как это реализуется?

Comment: Ищите в поисковиках "ковер серпиского реализация python"

Comment: а в чём проблема? вы не знаете, как рисовать линию, или не можете высчитать координаты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам псевдокод:

```
SierpinskiSieve(v1, v2, v3, recdepth) :
    if (recdepth == 0) :
        draw triangle (v1, v2, v3)
        return

    m1 = (v2 + v3)/2
    m2 = (v3 + v1)/2
    m3 = (v1 + v2)/2
    SierpinskiSieve(v1, m3, m2, recdepth - 1)
    SierpinskiSieve(m3, v2, m1, recdepth - 1)
    SierpinskiSieve(v2, m1, v3, recdepth - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Моя версия с использованием turtle, может кому-то пригодится. l это длина стороны треугольника, n это количество рекурсивно нарисованных треугольников Серпиского. Например `>>>sierpinski(100,1)` даст результат как на третьей картинке из вопроса.

```
from turtle import *
speed("fastest")

def sierpinski(l,n):
    assert (isinstance(l, int) or isinstance(l, float)) and l>0, 'parameter l is a positive float or integer'
    assert isinstance(n, int) and n>=0, 'parameter n is a whole number'      
    if n==0:
        for i in range(0,3):
            fd(l)
            left(120)
    else:
        sierpinski(l/2,n-1)
        fd(l/2)
        sierpinski(l/2,n-1)
        bk(l/2)
        left(60)
        fd(l/2)
        right(60)
        sierpinski(l/2,n-1)
        left(60)
        bk(l/2)
        right(60)
```

Comment: Не прошло и 6 лет!

Comment: Я добавлю более детальный ответ еще через 6 лет :)